# Jekyll. How to filter recent posts by category except current post?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I want to get the last 3 posts by category on a page, except for the current page in this filter.

My code is not working:

```
{% for cat in page.categories[0] %}
    {% for post in site.categories[cat] limit: 3 %}
        {% if post.title == page.title %}
            {% break %}
        {% endif %}
      <div class="item">
        <a href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}">
            <div class="image" style="background-image: url({{ post.image }});"></div>
            <div class="item-text main">
                <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
            </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace

`{% if post.title == page.title %}
  {% break %}
 {% endif %}`

with

`{% unless post.url == page.url %}`

Full Code

```
{% for cat in page.categories[0] %}
{% for post in site.categories[cat] limit: 3 %}
    {% unless post.url == page.url %}
  <div class="item">
    <a href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}">
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url({{ post.image }});"> 
        </div>
        <div class="item-text main">
            <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        </div>
    </a>
  </div>
 {% endunless %}    
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```